# MUI: cannot apply background color to Paper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style the MUI `<Paper>` component, however setting the background color isn't working. Following the online tutorials I'm applying the background-color CSS property to the root element of the `Paper` but the color remains white while other CSS properties - in this case `padding` and `text-align` work. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

```
import React from 'react';  
import { Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccessAlarm';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {  
        textAlign: 'center',
        padding: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#37474f',
        }
    
});

export default function Header() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return( 
        <Paper outlined square className={classes.root} 
        >
            <Typography variant="h2" component="h1"> 
                Pomodoro Cl
                <AccessAlarmIcon sx={{ fontSize: 45, color: 'red' }} />
                ck
            </Typography>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your attribute `outlined` is incorrect, it should be`variant="outlined"` as per the [documentation](https://mui.com/api/paper/#main-content).
For the `background-color` not working, you will need to add `!important` to the property so it takes precedence over mui's default styling.
Here's a working codesandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-smoke-y6yhv?file=/src/App.tsx